# Is there a way to transparently wrap comparable C structs in C++ generic classes?

Tags: c++, generics

I'm trying to create a generic class that wraps a struct from structures in a C library. Consider these two structure definitions.

```
struct s32 {
  int a:
  int b;
};

struct s64 {
  long a;
  long b;
};
```

I'm trying to determine if there is a generic construct in C++ which would let transparently create a wrapper around these structs such as I don't have to explicitly write the code to access the `long` or `int` variations.

Since I don't know what construct would provide this other than making an interface and implementing both versions - this is just pseudo code.

```
template <typename T, typename I> class SWrapper {
  T s;
  public:
  SWrapper(T _s) : s(_s) {};

  I get_a() { return this->s->a; }
}

class S32 : SWrapper<s32*, int> {};
class S64 : SWrapper<s64*, long> {};

int main(void) {
  s32 s1 = { 1, 2 };
  s64 s2 = { 3, 4 };
  SWapper* S = new S32(&s1); // I know this is incorrect
  S = new S64(&s2);          //  
  assert(s.get_a() == 3);
}
```

I know why this doesn't work. Templates are determined at compile time and so the compiler can't determine what `S` actually is when using the generic `SWapper` without actual type-parameters and using type-parameters would create an erasure that excludes the other type so they cannot both be assigned to the same address.

Besides C macros or implementing all the code for two classes implementing the same interface is there some construct in C++ to produce the same effect?

**[Update]**

After considering several patterns I've settled on a pattern which I consider to be "the least cost to write". It is very close to the answer by @JaMiT.

The benefits I see are:

- No need to completely implement the code that accesses the C struct's twice.
- No need to constantly redefined generic types `<>` when wrapper class is used.

Again please just consider this pseudo code.

```
class SWrapper {
private:
  const std::unique_ptr<s32> s32impl_;
  const std::unique_ptr<s64> s64impl_;
public:
  SWrapper(s32* s) : s32impl_(s),       s64impl_(nullptr) {};
  SWrapper(s64* s) : s32impl_(nullptr), s64impl_(s)       {};

  long get_a() {
    // could be improved with macros
    return (s32impl_->get() == nullptr) ? s32impl_->a : s64impl_->a;
  }
}
```

Comment: you need type erasure.

Comment: Take a look at `std::function` and see if that is the effect you are looking for.

Comment: How are you planning to handle the different types that would result from calling `get_a()` for different wrappers? Are we dealing with just `int` and `long` (and maybe other types that can convert to `long`) or might there be other, perhaps non-scalar, types involved?

Comment: @JaMiT I am limiting this to `int`, `long`, and other simple signed integer types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `S` is not so much that templates are determined at compile time, but rather than pointers cannot point to unrelated types. To give you the same setup without templates:

```
class A;
class B;
class C * S = ???  // Cannot point to another class.
```

You might see a connection between the classes you are trying to use, but to the compiler `SWrapper<s32*, int>` and `SWrapper<s64*, long>` are as different as `A` and `B`.

In order to have a pointer pointing to different types, the types need to share a common ancestor. This is not hard to do when you have enough restrictions on the structures you are getting from the C library. The question implies that these structures have a common logical structure, but differ in the types of members. The comments clarified that the types of the members could all be implicitly cast to a common type. (Specifically, they are all signed integers of some variety.) So one could define the interface you want to see:

```
class WrapBase {
    public:
        virtual ~WrapBase() {}

        virtual long get_a() = 0;
        virtual long get_b() = 0;
};
```

Note that the member functions return `long`. This is the type that things will be implicitly cast to. If needed, it could be `long long`.

Next, use your template to adapt this base to the various structures:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrap : public WrapBase {
    private:
        T & data;

    public:
        explicit Wrap(T & from_c) : data(from_c) {}

        long get_a() { return data.a; }
        long get_b() { return data.b; }
};
```

Now you can write functions that take wrapped structures as arguments. Well, presumably that is the sort of thing you want to do. Manually calling `new` is undesirable, but it does provide a quick-and-dirty demo showing the polymorphism in action.

```
    // Demonstration using the question's main() as context:
    WrapBase * S = new Wrap<s32>(s1);
    std::cout << "s1: {" << S->get_a() << ',' << S->get_b() << "};\n";
    delete S;
    S = new Wrap<s64>(s2);
    std::cout << "s2: {" << S->get_a() << ',' << S->get_b() << "};\n";
    delete S;
```

Since the polymorphism works for pointers, it will work for references used as function parameters.

---

One downside of the above is that you have to declare all the access functions twice. And there is additional work to get the values from the wrapped structures. An easier interface to code (and use?) would involved converting, rather than wrapping, the data. This involves a greater upfront cost when obtaining the data, but cheaper access costs. Whether or not this is an option depends on execution constraints, but it's probably worth trying to see how well it works.

```
struct Converted {
    long a;
    long b;

    template <typename T>
    explicit Converted(T & source) :
        a(source.a),
        b(source.b)
    {}
};
```

Again using `long` as the type to which everything can be implicitly converted. Now you can use the data with a more familiar access syntax. (If you still want getter functions -- a reasonable design choice -- the compiler should be able to inline them, something it could not do with the virtual functions.)

```
    // Demonstration using the question's main() as context:
    Converted S{s1};
    std::cout << "s1: {" << S.a << ',' << S.b << "};\n";
    Converted SS{s2};
    std::cout << "s2: {" << SS.a << ',' << SS.b << "};\n";
```

Comment: Thanks @Jamit - I was afraid this was the case and I am settling on a version of the "convert" approach. See the edit to my original approach. ( writing now ... )